# Uniform cost search in clojure

Tags: clojure

there seems to be a bug in this program I appreciate if someone could help

```
(defn findmincostindex [frontier]
  (loop [i 0 n 0]
    (if (< i (count frontier))
      (if (< (:cost (get frontier i)) (:cost (get frontier n)))
        (recur (inc i) i)
        (recur (inc i) n))
      n)))


(defn uniformcostsearch [graph start end]
  ((fn [frontier explored]
    (if (empty? frontier)
      "Failure"
      (let [pathwithmincost (findmincostindex (into [] frontier))
      ;(let [pathwithmincost (findmincostindex frontier)
            path (:path (get frontier pathwithmincost))
            cost (:cost (get frontier pathwithmincost))
            node (peek path)
            childs (keys (graph node))]
        (if (= node end)
          path
          (recur 
            (concat (subvec frontier 0 pathwithmincost) (subvec frontier (inc pathwithmincost))
              (map (fn [c] {:path (conj path c) :cost (+ cost ((graph node) c))})
                (filter #(not (contains? explored %)) childs)))
            (conj explored node))))))
    [{:path [start] :cost 0}] #{}))



(def graph {
        "Oradea" {
            "Zerind" 71,
            "Sibiu" 151
        },
        "Zerind" {
            "Oradea" 71,
            "Arad" 75
        },
        "Arad" {
            "Zerind" 75,
            "Sibiu" 140,
            "Timisoara" 118
        },
        "Sibiu" {
            "Oradea" 151,
            "Arad" 140,
            "Fagaras" 99,
            "Rimnicu Vilcea" 80
        },
        "Fagaras" {
            "Sibiu" 99,
            "Bucharest" 211
        },
        "Rimnicu Vilcea" {
            "Sibiu" 80,
            "Pitesti" 97,
            "Craiova" 146
        },
        "Timisoara" {
            "Arad" 118,
            "Lugoj" 111
        },
        "Lugoj" {
            "Timisoara" 111,
            "Mehadia" 70
        },
        "Pitesti" {
            "Rimnicu Vilcea" 97,
            "Craiova" 138,
            "Bucharest" 101
        },
        "Mehadia" {
            "Lugoj" 70,
            "Drobeta" 75
        },
        "Drobeta" {
            "Mehadia" 75,
            "Craiova" 120
        },
        "Craiova" {
            "Drobeta" 120,
            "Rimnicu Vilcea" 146,
            "Pitesti" 138
        },
        "Bucharest" {
            "Pitesti" 101,
            "Fagaras" 211,
            "Giurgiu" 90,
            "Urziceni" 85
        },
        "Giurgiu" {
            "Bucharest" 90
        },
        "Urziceni" {
            "Bucharest" 85,
            "Vaslui" 142,
            "Hirsova" 98
        },
        "Hirsova" {
            "Urziceni" 98,
            "Eforie" 86
        },
        "Eforie" {
            "Hirsova" 86
        },
        "Vaslui" {
            "Iasi" 92,
            "Urziceni" 142
        },
        "Iasi" {
            "Neamt" 87,
            "Vaslui" 92
        },
        "Neamt" {
            "Iasi" 87
        }})

(println (uniformcostsearch graph "Neamt" "Iasi"))
(println (uniformcostsearch graph "Neamt" "Vaslui"))
(println (uniformcostsearch graph "Bucharest" "Arad"))
```

it should output these lines

```
['Neamt', 'Iasi']
['Neamt', 'Iasi', 'Vaslui']
['Bucharest', 'Pitesti', 'Rimnicu Vilcea', 'Sibiu', 'Arad']
```

but instead it says:

> clojure.lang.LazySeq cannot be cast to
>   clojure.lang.IPersistentVector

when I use

```
(into [] frontier)
```

if I use frontier alone it says

> java.lang.NullPointerException

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The exception happens in the first `subvec` in your `recur`. You're recurring with the result of `concat`, which is a lazy sequence, and you can't take a subvector of a lazy sequence. A quick fix is to just wrap it in `vec`:

```
(vec (concat (subvec frontier 0 pathwithmincost) (subvec frontier (inc pathwithmincost))
              (map (fn [c] {:path (conj path c) :cost (+ cost ((graph node) c))})
                (remove explored childs))))
```

A few other tips:

1. `findmincostindex` is essentially a reimplementation of [`min-key`](http://conj.io/store/v1/org.clojure/clojure/1.7.0/clj/clojure.core/min-key/) which is less general, and you could probably make this cleaner by using that.
2. Sets are functions too, and return the argument (truthy values) if it is a member of the set. You can use this to improve a little on `(filter #(not (contains? explored %)) childs)))` - for instance `(remove explored childs)`
3. Your `let` could be made a bit shorter by using [destructuring](http://clojure.org/special_forms#binding-forms).

Here's my attempt:

```
(let [[idx {:keys [path cost]}] (apply min-key (comp :cost second) (map-indexed vector frontier))
      node (peek path)
      childs (keys (graph node))]
```

The process here is

1. `(map-indexed vector frontier)` makes the `frontier` into pairs of index and node.
2. `min-key` finds the pair which has the lowest value for `(:cost (second pair))`.
3. `let` binds the name `idx` to the index of that pair, and `path` and `cost` to the `:path` and `:cost` keys of the node.